# Raspi AdHoc to receive network credentials

Tags: c++, linux, networking

If any of you are familiar with Google's chromecast, I am trying to get a raspberry pi to connect to a network similarly.  Specifically, I want a daemon in the background which is checking the network connection and if the Raspi can't connect to a network, then I want it to start broadcasting an AdHoc network and run DHCP server.

The Raspi will then listen for instructions over the network for wifi credentials and upon receiving them, will try to connect. If the raspi successfully connects or an ethernet cable is plugged in, the AdHoc/DHCPd will shut down and the new connection will be used.

I am new to linux networking commands so I was wondering if there was something I was doing wrong in setting up these connections. Here are the relevant c++ scripts:

In case credentials are already saved:

```
void NetworkConnectionMonitor::connectToRemeberedWifi()
{
    system("wpa_supplicant -B -i wlan0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf"); 
    system("dhclient -1 wlan0");
}
```

Adhoc connection:

```
void NetworkConnectionMonitor::startAdHoc()
{
    system("ifconfig wlan0 down");
    system("iwconfig wlan0 mode ad-hoc");
    system("iwconfig wlan0 key aaaaa11111");
    system("iwconfig wlan0 essid RPi");
    system("ifconfig wlan0 10.0.0.200 netmask 255.255.255.0
    system("/usr/sbin/dhcpd wlan0");
}

void NetworkConnectionMonitor::stopAdHoc()
{
    system("service isc-dhcp-server stop");
    system("ifconfig wlan0 down");
}
```

When I receive new credentials after calling stopAdHoc()

```
void NetworkConnectionMonitor::connectToWifi(string essid, string psk)
{
    system("wpa_supplicant -B -i wlan0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf");
    system("wpa_cli add_network");
    system("wpa_cli set_network 0 ssid " + essid); 
    system("wpa_cli set_network 0 psk " + psk); 
    system("wpa_cli enable_network 0"); 
    system("wpa_cli save_config"); 
    system("dhclient -1 wlan0");
}
```

If the network goes down I call this before calling start ad hoc

```
void NetworkConnectionMonitor::stopWifi()
{
    system("wpa_cli terminate");
}
```

wpa_supplicant.conf (Before credentials are added):

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
```

/etc/network/interfaces

```
auto lo wlan0

iface lo inet loopback

allow-hotplug etho0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
```

The errors that I am receiving are too numerous to list here, but the adhoc seems to start up just fine and I can connect to it and successfully send packets through the listening port. However, when I try to switch to a Wifi connection it seems like there is some conflict still between the dhclient and the dhcpd.

If there is an easier way to do this I would love to hear it. If not anyone have an idea why this isn't working?

Comment: There two basic problems with this: first, you have to handle errors. Calling commands one after the other, and hoping that all goes well, or else the world collapses, will surely lead to troubles. Second, dhclient is normally a resident software, as DHCP needs regular updates, so when shutting down an interface with dhclient, you'll have to kill the resident instance as well. Also, with wpa_supplicant, I'd rather generate the needed config file instead of using wpa_cli to change the parameters on the fly.